Determining Critical Temperature of Oxygen from Six $p$-$V$ Diagrams
So the question is to plot six $p$-$V$ curves for oxygen at various temperatures ranging from 80 K to 170 K, using the Van der Waals equation. Having done that, the next part asks to estimate the critical temperature of oxygen using these plots. And the question gives a hint that the critical point is when the curve becomes 'horizontal'.
The given constants are: $a = 0.14$ and $b =$ $3.2*10^{-5}$ (SI units)
I have tried for so long to determine the critical temperature from these plots, but unable to do.
And the 'horizontal' points are:
For T = 80 K : (V,P):
(3.46890422*10^{-4},948788.3713)
$(4.842269467*10^{-5}, -19207617.86)$
$(2.566354922*10^{-5}, -317533670.5)$
For T = 100 K: (V,P):
$(2.5585852797*10^{-4},1575529.804)$   //Rejected, out of range.
$(5.306221682*10^{-5},-10249464.5)$
$(2.513383614*10^{-5}, -342707315.3)$
For T = 120 K: (V,P):
$(1.968043693*10^{-4}, 2439136.983)$
$(5.916584624*10^{-5},-3267647.899)$
$(2.468089504*10^{-5},-366141489.1)$
For T = 130 K: (V,P)$
$(1.713253946*10^{-4},2987894.832)$
$(6.326068935*10^{-5},-408839.8638)$
$(2.447647961*10^{-5},-377343430)$
For $T = 150 K: (V,P)$
$(2.410280326*10^{-5}, -398903411.6)$
$(1.226401156*10^{-4},4450668.009)$
$(7.777796963*10^{-5},4099618.585)$
For $T = 170 K: (V,P)$
$(2.376757523*10{^-5},-419517046)$
I have tried to average all 10^-5 separately and all 10^-4 separately but both give answers far from 156 K (About 100-120 K)
The correct answer should be ~~8a/(27Rb) ~= 155.92 K. (T_c)
Any hints / ideas would be appreciated.

Without trying to reproduce your plots, it seems like you are plotting in a wrong way. Some hints:

The part below $V=b$ with negative pressure is not physical. Don’t plot it.
Use logarithmic axes.
Use a bigger range.
Start with a low temperature and plot the diagram such that you see local extrema.


Thanks for the hints.
Unfortunately, the question specifically asks to plot from 210^-4 to 210^-5 only.
I might try the logarithmic axes, but will learn how to implement it on MATLAB.
For the time being though, what I do not understand, am I looking for horizontal line(I.e. curve gets flat) or at inflection / max points? And what relation do these have with the critical temperature?

@Nero: Unfortunately, the question specifically asks to plot from 210^-4 to 210^-5 only – I haven’t checked (and I also cannot since you do not specify what flavour of the vdW model you are using) but that probably is a hint. And you are not plotting in that region anyway. Also, you can still make the y axis logarithmic. — am I looking for horizontal line(I.e. curve gets flat) or at inflection / max points? – First look for curves with local extrema. Then play with the parameters and things should become clear. If not, that’s a separate question (that also has probably been answered).

Sorry but what do you mean specifically by 'local extrema' ?
I know that they stand for many things: inflection point, min, max, global min, and global max.
But then why does the question for instance say to look at the points where the curve becomes horizontal?
Or did I misunderstand something?
If you could re-direct me to a question that was answered relating critical temperature with PV diagrams I would appreciate it!

Sorry but what do you mean specifically by 'local extrema' ? I know that they stand for many things: inflection point, min, max, global min, and global max. – A local extremum is a local maximum or minimum, i.e., a $V$ where $p(V)>p(V')$ for all other $V'$ in a sufficiently close neighbourhood of $V$ (or lower, respectively). An inflection point is never a local extremum. — But then why does the question for instance say to look at the points where the curve becomes horizontal? – I didn’t say you are ultimately looking for these cases; I said that you should look for these first.
